# How can I get an image uri from this code that initializes the camera action?

Tags: android

I need to create an alert dialog that picks photos from either the camera
or gallery and then save them to firebase storage and database.
However I don't know how to convert this bitmap to uri and can't get image uri from the camera action result.

```
activityResultLauncher1 = registerForActivityResult(new 
ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result)
        {
            if(result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null)
            {
                Bundle bundle = result.getData().getExtras();
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
                profilePic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by keeping an URL to my newly created image before sending the intent.

```java
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
  File photoFile = createImageFile();
  // I save it to viewModel for example
  mViewModel.setPhotoUri(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
  
  Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
          "my.app.id",
          photoFile);
  takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
  startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}

// after photo being made
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // ...
  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mViewModel.getPhotoURI(), bmOptions);
  // ...
}
```

Though I think it's not the most sophisticated way, as `onActivityResult` is deprecated.

Comment: But startForActivityResult is also deprecated.